# Why getAttribute returns null?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamics-crm-2011, xrm

I am using dynamics CRM. I have created one HTML web resource and added to Contacts form. Code,

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>OData</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getAllAttribute() {

            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Xrm.Page.getAttribute();
        }
    </script>
    <button onclick="getAllAttribute();">Attributes!</button>
    <p id="demo">Value will be displayed here</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, when I click on *Attributes!* button, `demo` paragraph gets null, why it is not giving names of all attributes on page?

Comment: what is `Xrm.Page`? is it described on page?

Comment: Actually it works under dynamics crm. http://www.xrm.com/xrm/xrm.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be use `window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes` or `window.parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute()` instead of `Xrm.Page.getAttribute();`.

see here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/gg328474.aspx

Comment: I am getting error: Webpage error details

Message: 'Xrm.Page.data.entity' is null or not an object

Comment: ok since the 'Xrm.Page.data.entity itself is null that is why you are not getting the attributes may be.

Comment: I am on Contacts page, using web resource, why it is null?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434885/xrm-is-undefined-in-dynamics-crm-2011

Comment: here are some guidelines http://ms-crm-2011-beta.blogspot.in/2011/09/xrmpagedataentityattributeget-is-null.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62154/discussion-between-pranitkothari-and-suchit).